# Fulfilling Kri'at Shema by reading it as a Torah reader

Tags: halacha, torah-reading, shema

Let's say someone is a Torah reader. The weekly Torah portion is Va'etchanan, which contains the first pargraph of *Kri'at Shema*.

He arrives in shul exactly at the time when he must start to read the Torah for the congregation. He knows that at his reading pace, he will reach the section starting with the verses of *Shema Yisra'el* (Deut. 6) very close to the ending time of *Kri'at Shema*.

Can he fulfill the mitzvah of having read the morning *Shema* while he is reading the Torah portion for the congregation assuming he has the proper *kavana* (intent) to do this? Is there a rule that one cannot fulfill two mizvot simultaneously, and would this rule apply, or not apply, here?

Comment: If he's cutting it that close, he should really just read it to himself during a Mi SheBeirakh.

Comment: @DoubleAA If he were a *Ba'al Kri'a* as me, he would be the one doing *Mi Sheberach* too, so that's not possible. (I won't go into my shul's practices, but some of the gabbaim who stand next to me can't read Hebrew that well, hence I'm doing the Mi Sheberach. I know that an inability to read Hebrew well makes a poor gabbai choice. Decision isn't mine, though, and I've registered a complaint more than once. *Shomer peta'im*, maybe?)

Comment: More like _Shomer petayim_. The Alef is silent. The Chirik is on the Yud.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mishna Berakhot 2:1

> היה קורא בתורה, והגיע זמן המקרא--אם כיוון את ליבו, יצא; ואם לאו, לא יצא.‏
>   If he was reading in the Torah and it came time to read [Shema]: if he intended, he fulfilled his obligation, and if not, he did not. (my translation)

Rambam (Shema 2:1) and ShA (OC 60:5) rule this way as well. So "assuming he has the proper *kavana* (intent) to do this" then he fulfills his obligation.

Comment: this answer is perhaps not suffisant if you explain not the full understanding of Kiven LIBO according to the halacha

Comment: @kouty The questioner said to assume he has proper intent. That would probably include intent to fulfill the mitzva, to accept the yoke of heaven, knowing the meaning of the words, etc.

Comment: I believe he also needs to mention going out of Egypt on time as well, since he is only reciting the Shma and V'ahavta. (He is missing the V'haya and VaYomer portions. It is the Vayomer that contains a reference to Yetzias Mitzrayim.)

Comment: @DavidKenner mentioning going out to Egipt follows the timing of KS?

Comment: @DavidKenner If I'm not mistaken, one has fulfilled the mitzvah of Kri'at Shema by reciting just the 1st paragraph. I had heard that one of the reasons for reciting just the 1st paragraph during *Birkot Hashachar* was to fulfill the mitzvah in case one will not reach the later part prior to *Sof Z'man*.

Comment: @DavidKenner anyway the same aliyah contains עבדים היינו

Comment: @danf how much of shema is deorayta and how much is derbanan is a machloket rishonim. Most assume that if using the shema at the beginning of davening to fulfil ones obligation, one should recite at that point all 3 chapters.

Comment: @ kouty; DanF; Double AA; Gemara Brachos 13b (near the bottom area) says that Rebbi would mention Yetzias Mitzrayim "on time". I believe all or most opinions hold that to mean it "should be" said on time. However, one does not violate a D'oraisa by mentioning it later. I thought I saw some opinion learning that the Rambam seems to hold it is a mitzvah to say it on time; but that would be learned out from the Rambam at best.

Comment: @ Heshy; Good one

Comment: @DavidKenner See Betzel HaChokhmah 1:1 http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1808&st=&pgnum=9&hilite= that if you don't have time to say Shema and Birkhos HaTorah, to say the first two paragraphs of Shema first, and then BT, even if the time might then pass.